# Cppcheck stop checking unusedStructMember

Tags: cppcheck

**cppcheck version**：2.3

1.Scan the following code (rsvd.c)

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    // cppcheck-suppress unusedStructMember
    int b;
    int c;
} test;


int main()
{
    test A;
    A.a = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

run `cppcheck --inline-suppr --enable=all rsvd.c`
The results are as follows(as expected):

> Checking rsvd.c ...
>
> rsvd.c:7:9: style: struct member 'test::c' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
>
> int c;
>
> rsvd.c:14:9: style: Variable 'A.a' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]
>
> A.a = 5;

2.Scan the following code

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} test;


int main()
{
    test A = {1, 2, 3};
    return 0;
}
```

The results are as follows(not expected):

> Checking rsvd.c ...
>
> rsvd.c:3:9: style: struct member 'test::a' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
>
> int a;
>
> rsvd.c:4:9: style: struct member 'test::b' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
>
> int b;
>
> rsvd.c:5:9: style: struct member 'test::c' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
>
> int c;
>
> rsvd.c:11:12: style: Variable 'A' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]
>
> test A = {1, 2, 3};

In the preceding code, a value has been assigned to the structure member variable. This is a false positive of the tool. How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false positive in Cppcheck. I filed https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/10699 for the problem.

Unfortunately the braced initializer is not handled well in all cases. This is being improved.
In some cases such warnings go away when you switch to `(`/`)` instead but you should not do that.